# I'm trying to call a svelte route through a url in the browser. It give me a 404

Tags: api, routes, svelte

I am trying to use a svelte app to call an api route. I made a simple svelte app with `npm init svelte@next svelte-api-calling`. I added the file `routes/api/callthis/[name].ts`, and it looks like this:

```
export async function get({ params }) {
    const {name} = params;
    console.log(name);
};
```

I start the app with `npm run dev`. I tried to call this api route by typing `http://localhost:5173/api/callthis/check` into my browser. I expected my console to log `check`. It gave me a 404 error. How do I get this route to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how routing works in SvelteKit.

First if you want an api route you make a file `+server.js` (or ts), so in your case the full structure would be `routes/api/callthis/[name]/+server.js`
(the code in the file itself can be similar)

Second this api runs on the server (it is after all an api), so the console.log would be in the *server console* and not in the browser.

You are also not returning anything from the api (yet)

---

*This answer holds for the version of SvelteKit as it is on 20.02.2023, when using StackOverflow always remember to check the date because technology can change rapidly*

Comment: Also, `get` should be `GET`.